# Unity3D - Despite using Time.deltaTime, my camera and player move faster at higher framerates

Tags: unity, 3d, frame-rate, time

I'm pretty new to c# and Unity so I wouldn't be surprised if I had made some stupid mistakes, but as far as I know, I don't think I misused Time.deltaTime. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Movement Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    private float crouchMultiplier = 1f;

    private Vector3 velocity;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool isCrouched;
    private float velocityDecay = 1f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * crouchMultiplier * velocityDecay * Time.deltaTime);
        
        Debug.Log(Time.deltaTime);
        
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            isCrouched = true;
            gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1f, 1);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            crouchMultiplier = 1f;
            gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 2f, 1);
            velocityDecay = 1;
            isCrouched = false;
        }

        if (isCrouched)
        {
            if (velocityDecay > 0.2f && isGrounded)
            {
                crouchMultiplier = 2.5f;
                velocityDecay *= 0.995f;
            }
        }




        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Camera Script:

````
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Transform playerBody;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    
    float xRotation = 0f;
        
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90);
        
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Assuming the PlayerMovement script is on the same object as CharacterController, it looks to me like `Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;` would cause your character to move faster the further they were from 0,0,0. Is that intentional behavior? Normally I would expect those to be something like Vector3.right and Vector3.forward.

Comment: @ChrisMills-Price `transform.right` and `transform.forward` are relative to the transform's heading. They do not increase with distance from the world origin. `Vector3.right` and `Vector3.forward` are relative to the world (i.e. east and north respectively).

Comment: @Kevin Wow, absolutely. Not sure what I was thinking there, obviously nothing correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time.deltaTime` is not always 100% accurate. It can sometimes be slightly off if the framerate is extremely high or low, or if you have modified `Time.timeScale`

Movement is usually better handled in `FixedUpdate()`. This syncs it with the physics engine and gives a more consistent experience regardless of framerate and timescale.

A good approach is to read input in the `Update()` function but apply motion in the `FixedUpdate()` function. An extremely simple example:

```
float speed = 5;
float horizontalInput = 0;

void Update() {
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    //You can use Time.deltaTime here and Unity will automatically
    //detect that it's in a FixedUpdate and give the appropriate value.
    //Or you can use Time.fixedDeltaTime if you prefer
    transform.position += transform.right * horizontalInput * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: I can't help but think this might be for a rigidbody as my player clips through some objects when I use this format. Either that or just bad implementation on my behalf

Comment: Setting position with `transform.position` does indeed clip through collisions. You'll want to use `CharacterController.Move` if you're using a character controller, or `Rigidbody.MovePosition` and related methods if using a rigidbody, to move in a collision-aware fashion.

Comment: Awesome thanks, do you have any idea how the same would work with my camera, when i put the camera in fixedupdate its jittery

Comment: I didn't mean for the example to be used as-is; it's just a simple example of how you can tie `Update()` input with `FixedUpdate()` movement logic.
If the camera is jittering when it collides with objects, that could be the positioning code fighting with the physics - e.g. your code tries to put the camera inside a wall, then the physics engine moves it, then your code tries to put it back in the wall... This can be tricky to fix and the best solution depends on your game. If it's jittering all the time, something else is wrong. If you can't figure out what, you might try LERPing the camera.

Comment: No I mean the camera sensitivity is also different based on framerate

Comment: @BasedSoup Ah, okay. Mouse motion might be better handled in `Update()` instead of `FixedUpdate()`. Also, axis sensitivity should be handled in the Input settings (i.e. you shouldn't be multiplying by a sensitivity in your code) and IIRC you shouldn't multiply mouse motion by `Time.deltaTime` either since it represents the total mouse motion over the last frame.

Comment: So try just `float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");` and `float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")`